# PowerShell: using @{Add=''} sometimes work and sometimes it does not

Tags: powershell

When an object can have multiple values on an object like, I use most of the time:
***-Object @{Add=''}*** or ***-Object @{Remove=''}***. But I notice that this not works all the time, than you need to set all the values because other wise it replaces the existing values.

For example, when I use:

```
Set-Mailbox "Contoso Executives" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{Add='tempassistants@contoso.com','tempassistants@contoso.com'}
```

The *@{Add=''}* is working. But when I use:

```
Set-RetentionPolicy "MRM Policy" -RetentionPolicyTagLinks @{Add='tag1','tag2'}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot convert value "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type

Why does this happens? RetentionPolicyTagLinks can have multiple values in the same way as GrantSendOnBehalfTo can have.

Comment: Just try without `Add=`. RetentionPolicyTagLinks expects an array of [RetentionPolicyTagIdParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/ff326776(v=exchg.140)) s

Comment: Yes, but this will delete all the tags in the same way as you add addresses to GrantSendOnBehalfTo

Comment: First use `Get-RetentionPolicy` to retrieve the existing tags. Then add the new ones to that list an set it with `Set-RetentionPolicy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is within the format of your RetentionPolicyTagLinks parameter.

Try the documentation below to help you with storing it in a variable first:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/add-or-remove-retention-tags-exchange-2013-help

Comment: Thanks! this is working. But still find it strange why I can't use Add= on `Set-RetentionPolicy`
I use add= on properties where you can set multiple values like:
`Set-AntiPhishPolicy -Identity $User.Policy -TargetedUsersToProtect @{add="user1;user1@fabrikam.com"}`

I only face that this method it not working on:
`Set-RetentionPolicy "MRM Policy" -RetentionPolicyTagLinks @{Add='tag1'}`